# Ktor seems to be swallowing exceptions

Tags: ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

I am using Ktor with kotlin multiplatform and I am trying to figure out why I am not getting any exceptions that get thrown. In my client configuration I am using the `HttpResonseValidator` to check the status code coming back

```
private val client = HttpClient(clientEngine) {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer(Json.nonstrict)
        }
//        addDefaultResponseValidation()
        HttpResponseValidator{

            validateResponse { response: HttpResponse ->
                val statusCode = response.status.value
                when (statusCode) {
                    in 300..399 -> throw RedirectResponseException(response)
                    in 400..499 -> throw ClientRequestException(response)
                    in 500..599 -> throw ServerResponseException(response)
                }

                if (statusCode >= 600) {
                    throw ResponseException(response)
                }
            }

            handleResponseException { cause: Throwable ->
                throw cause
            }
        }
    }
```

I am returning http status code `401` error on my server for testing so I should see my code throw a `ClientRequestException` and the `validateResponse` does get called but I never see any exceptions in the console and my app just stops without any indication anything happened.

this is my call

```
private suspend fun getDataForUrl(url:String, callback: (MyObject?) -> Unit){
    val response = client.get<MyObject>(url)
    callback(response)
}
```

Which is called via

```
fun getData(callback: (MyObject?) -> Unit){
    launch(dispatcher()){
        getDataForUrl("$BASE_URL", callback)
    }
}
```

When I surround the call with a try/catch

```
try{
    val response = client.get<MyObject>(url)
catch(e:Exception){
}
```

I do get the exception but I dont really like that its getting caught here and not in the upper levels of my code.

Why is it getting swallowed up when there isn't a try/catch around it?

Comment: what exactly does `dispatcher()` do?

Comment: @Lucho For android it just is this `internal actual fun dispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO`

Comment: Ok great, I can't notice anything atm BUT can you try just removing the validator to check  if it works without it and let the rest be (I believe Ktor by default throws exception on 400, 500 series, not sure about 300). Does it throw for you then?

Comment: I didnt have a validator before and still was not getting exceptions, I was using `addDefaultResponseValidation` which is where I copied most of the code for my validator and I still was not getting anything

Comment: I just tried it out and getting `FATAL EXCEPTION`. So I'm sure it's not Ktor that is the issue and "pretty" sure it's about how you simply are running your coroutines here. Reason you are seeing it with try/catch is because you are still in the parent coroutine context to actually catch the exception and print it. So my suggestion to you when running you MPP code that basically going to run in a coroutine, make sure that you "launch" it from your Activity/fragment so it "bubbles" all the way up, meaning the function you calling from Android is `suspend`.

Comment: Not sure if that made sense?...

Comment: I use a `callbackFlow` that wraps the call to the common code which does the network request and I am now suspecting that is the culprit seeing that you said its working fine for you. I will try without that and see

Comment: @tyczj I am also having same issue. tried all the available answer but not working. Did you find any answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

I had this `FATAL EXCEPTION` in my Kotlin multiplatform project too.

My Ktor method looks like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun requestToken(userName: String, password: String): AuthResponse {
    return client.post {
        url(urlOauth)
        accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
        body = FormDataContent(Parameters.build {
            append("grant_type", "password")
            append("username", userName)
            append("password", password)
        })
    }
}
```

The `HttpResponseValidator` is used if everything works fine. But when I force an error, e.g., with a wrong URL, the `HttpResponseValidator` isn't used, and my app, in this case an iOS app, crashes.

When I open the generated Swift class, I see this comment added to my method:

```
/**
 @note This method converts instances of CancellationException to errors.
 Other uncaught Kotlin exceptions are fatal.
*/
```

This means that all other errors are crashing my app. The `CancellationException` has something to do with the `suspend`.

To prevent the crash and get the error, I added `@Throws(CancellationException::class, ResponseException::class)`. The method now looks like this:

```kotlin
@Throws(CancellationException::class, ResponseException::class)
suspend fun requestToken(userName: String, password: String): AuthResponse {
    return client.post {
        url(urlOauth)
        accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
        body = FormDataContent(Parameters.build {
            append("grant_type", "password")
            append("username", userName)
            append("password", password)
        })
    }
}
```

This is how I use it:

```swift
ApiKt.requestToken(userName: "xxx", password: "xxx") { (response: AuthResponse?, error: Error?) in
    if let response = response {
        print("access token: \(response.accessToken)")
    } else if let error = error {
        print("failed to load access token. error: \(error)")
    } else {
        print("Something strange has happened. We have received neither a response nor an error.")
    }
}
```

When I now force an error, the app doesn't crash. Instead, I get an error and print it out (in this case).

Finally, I don't know why the `HttpResponseValidator` isn't used in case of an error, but this prevents the `FATAL EXCEPTION`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue where my custom HttpResponseValidator was called just fine for response status codes other than 401.
After further investigation I found out, that my breakpoint in DefaultResponseValidation.kt (as used by addDefaultResponseValidation) was triggered instead.
I do not quite understant why validateResponse() was triggered at all as addDefaultResponseValidation() is never called in my code. But maybe this is the default when using the default Http Client.
However, the idea that status code 401 would trigger some default code prior in the execution change (that would return before my validator was called), led me to trying out

```
expectSuccess = false
```

which solved the issue for me.